# Track ecommerce in Angular ngx-google-analytics

Tags: angular, google-analytics

I'm using this package to track page views and events in my Angular application:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-google-analytics

However, i also want to track the e-commerce sells.

I'm trying to do this using the 'gtag()' function of the service:

```
constructor(
    private analyticsService: GoogleAnalyticsService
  ) { }

checkoutFunction(){
    this.analyticsService.gtag('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
        'id': 1234,                     // Transaction ID. Required.
        'revenue': '100.99'               // Grand Total.
      })

    this.analyticsService.gtag('ecommerce:send');
}
```

Why is it not working? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: same problem !!!